# TFS - WIT Customization - Define a custom action

Tags: tfs, custom-action, workitem

I'm working with TFS 2013 and VS2013 to modify a work item template but there are some issues I cannot resolve.

1. I want only the person who is assigned to a work item to be able to modify this. Is there any opportunity to set a general rule for this? I already tried to set each field readonly if the authorized user is not equal to the assigned user. But that didn't work for me, I suspect this is because of the difference between display name and system user (domain).
2. I also want to create a custom action, which automaticly changes the "assignedTo"-User. Unfortunatly I didn't find any proper guide how to define a custom action. Most guides explanes where an action is refered in a transition, but not where it is defined. Do you have any suggestions where to find such kind of guide?

Comment: Silly question: What happens if the Assigned User goes is out of the office and another person picks up the task? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: The problem is that the item has to be approved by a member of one tfs group, checking if the effort is okay. But after that approval this group shouldn't be able to do changes on the item.
So it would be better to make it editable to the group the assigned user belongs too..

Comment: I usually try and discourage clients from these kind of changes.  As Daniel says, you're likely to run into access issues and you're messing with your template unnecessarily.  I'd use TFS Alerts instead, so if someone in the approval group changes the effort and the state is = Approved (for example) then notify someone.  Another option is to use Area security.  So once a Work Item is moved out of the approval team's Area Path then they no longer have rights to edit it.

Comment: The only way to "make a work item readonly" is to make every field readonly. Note that not all fields can be made readonly.